# Templates in primefaces mobile

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, mobile-website

How to create templates in primefaces mobile, since the root tag is f:view, and not the html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The XML root element doesn't matter. It merely holds the XML name space declarations. The key is that you should have a `<f:view renderKitId="PRIMEFACES_MOBILE">` in the master template. So the following kickoff example of the master template should work as good:

```
<f:view 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:pm="http://primefaces.org/mobile"
    renderKitId="PRIMEFACES_MOBILE"
>
    <ui:insert name="some" />
</f:view>
```

Template client looks just the same as usual:

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:pm="http://primefaces.org/mobile"
>
    <ui:define name="some">
        ...
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick answer. Can you please also tell how can I show Loading bar for page to page navigation.(Loading bar is working OK when navigating from one pm:view to another, but how to show it for page to page navigation)

Comment: Or should I post a separate question for that?

Comment: where should we place pm:page is it as <ui:define><pm:page><pm:view ../></pm:page></ui:define> or <pm:page><pm:view><ui:define.../><ui:define  .../></pm:view></pm:page>